# How can I get the value of an input and split the words by comma?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a search feature for my ecom project. What I'm trying to do is take the data from an input in `index.html`, and then redirect to `search.html` while still being able to hold the data, but the page just reloads and nothing is showing up in the console field.

I'm using vanilla JavaScript and running into some issues.

This is my HTML

```
  <form action="search.html">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search for products"
      id="search-query"
    />
  </form>
```

and this is my JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("search-query").addEventListener("focus", function () {
  const search = document.getElementById("search-query").value;
  const searchResults = search.split(" ");
  console.log(searchResults);
});
```

I'm using the split method because I want each word separated by a comma. I plan on implementing a feature that displays images based on each word, but for now I just want the results to log to the console so I know I'm not getting an undefined, but nothing I try seems to be working.

I was able to get the code working just fine when I was only logging the value of the input, but I need a way to redirect to `search.html`, which is why I wrapped it in the `form`.

Comment: Do you need like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/XWEyLrG

Comment: Yes. Very similar to this. Thank you. I was off by a few things, mainly the "input". I'm curious if you know if using form is the only way to redirect to another page.

Comment: Yes, Form redirection should work.

Comment: You could use localStorage

Comment: @DavidPiper  **window.location.href="page.html"** -> go to **page**

Answer (score 0):

Change the eventlistener to `input` and not `focus` as the focus will work only when the input is focused and not on user input value.

**Modified snippet:**

```js
const search = document.getElementById("search-query");
search.addEventListener("input", function () {
  const searchValue = search.value;
  const searchResults = searchValue.split(" ");
  console.log(searchResults);
});
```

```html
  <form action="search.html">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search for products"
      id="search-query"
    />
  </form>
```

Comment: This works. However, when I go to another page, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`. When I get that for functions I tend to just wrap them in a try/catch (return) but it's not working for addEventListener. Any ideas? I'll also note my script tag is at the bottom of the body on each page.

Comment: @DavidPiper, `addEventListener` should be only on the first page right? Why do you have it in second page? If you have separate script in second page then there should be a matching `id` in the html element for which you add `eventListener`.

Comment: Well I am using the same `app.js` page for all my pages. I'm making an ecom website. Though I may have gotten to the point in my project where I need to start thinking about a database which is why I'm getting so many errors.

Comment: @DavidPiper, Without enough info its hard to help. And also I hope I answered for whatever you asked here as a question. For additional questions, you can raise a different question.